# Getting error while selecting drop down value in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

From drop down, I am not able to select the value from dropdown.

**HTML Code :**

```
<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-varindex="9" onchange="SetVariableValue('9', this, 'DESCENDANT - DROPDOWN')" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$drp85" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="-1">--Select--</option>
<option value="Please don't hesitate">Please don't hesitate </option>
<option value="Please reach out to us">Please reach out to us</option>
<option value="Remember we are here for you">Remember we are here for you</option>
<option value="If you need help">If you need help</option>
<option value="If you ever need additional help">If you ever need additional help</option>
</select>
```

**Selenium WebDriver Code :**

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85"));
selectbyindex=new Select(dropdown);
selectbyindex.selectByIndex(1);
```

Getting exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated".
```

Can anyone help where I am making mistake?

Comment: The `option-value` may not be visible unless you click it. Try, using the `click()` method before using selectByIndex(). If this doesn't work, try adding `wait` until the dropdown is actually visible, before you try to select the options.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the drop-down to be visible first and then select:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85"))));
```

Comment: Supporting html for dropdown

<span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85-container">
<span id="select2-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85-container" class="select2-selection__rendered" title="--Select--">--Select--</span>
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
<b role="presentation"/>
</span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"/>

Comment: I think you are using the wrong locator. Try the with Xpath ID contains- //*[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drp85')]